# Chrome is exporting wrong "file extension" instead of xls

Tags: php, mysql, google-chrome, phpexcel

i am new to phpexcel, so I use the code attached to export data from database to xls file. It works fine in any other browser, except Chrome, where the file downloaded have no "extension"  instead xls. 
It is something wrong with my code or it's a browser setting that shoud be modified? Can someone help me? Thanks

File downloaded [**Inventário Livros (20-05-2015)-**]

***My Code:***

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("Atlantic/Cape_Verde");
require_once '../../assets/PHPExcel_1.8.0/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once '../../assets/PHPExcel_1.8.0/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$Archive = "Inventário Livros";
$date = date('d/m/Y');

require '../conexao/conexao.php';

$objPHPExcel->getProperties()
        ->setCreator("RELM")
        ->setLastModifiedBy("RELM")
        ->setTitle("Inventário Livros")
        ->setSubject("Inventário")
        ->setDescription("")
        ->setKeywords("")
        ->setCategory("");

$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Calibri');
$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(11);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('9')->setRowHeight(20);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(5);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(9);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(40);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(30);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(12);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(12);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(12);

//=======================================Cabeçalho do Doc==============================================//
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C7', "Relação dos livros existentes na biblioteca");
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('C7:F7');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getStyle('C7:F7')
        ->getAlignment()
        ->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getStyle('C7:F7')
        ->getFont()
        ->setBold(true);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getStyle('C7:F7')
        ->getFont()
        ->setSize(14);

//=======================================Imagem==============================================//
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setName('header');
$objDrawing->setDescription('Cabeçalho da pagina');
$objDrawing->setPath('../../images/header.png');
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('C1');
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());

//=================================Conteudo(posiçao e estilo)==============================//
$y = 9;

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue("A" . $y, 'Nº')
        ->setCellValue("B" . $y, 'Estante')
        ->setCellValue("C" . $y, 'Obra')
        ->setCellValue("D" . $y, 'Autor')
        ->setCellValue("E" . $y, 'Categoria')
        ->setCellValue("F" . $y, 'Ano Esc.')
        ->setCellValue("G" . $y, 'Obs.');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getStyle('A9:G9')
        ->getFill()
        ->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)
        ->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFEEEEEE');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getStyle('A9:G9')
        ->getAlignment()
        ->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getStyle('A9:G9')
        ->getFont()
        ->setBold(true);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getStyle('A9:G9')
        ->getFont()
        ->setSize(12);


$borders = array(
    'borders' => array(
        'allborders' => array(
            'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,
            'color' => array('argb' => 'FF000000'),
        )
    ),
);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getStyle('A9:G9')
        ->applyFromArray($borders);

$query = "SELECT * FROM book AS B INNER JOIN category AS C ON B.category_id=C.id_category INNER JOIN scholarity AS S ON B.scholarity_id=S.id_scholarity ORDER BY number";
$res = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {

    $y++;

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->getStyle('A' . $y . ":G" . $y)
            ->applyFromArray($borders);

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue("A" . $y, $row['number'])
            ->setCellValue("B" . $y, $row['shelf'])
            ->setCellValue("C" . $y, $row['title'])
            ->setCellValue("D" . $y, $row['author'])
            ->setCellValue("E" . $y, $row['category_name'])
            ->setCellValue("F" . $y, $row['scholarity_name'])
            ->setCellValue("G" . $y, $row['obs']);
}

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= "' . $Archive . ' (' . $date . ') " ');
header('Cache-Control: max-age-0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');

exit; ?>
```

Comment: Your filename suggestion does not contain the extension. Hier I added one. header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= "' . $Archive . ' (' . $date . ').xls " ')

Comment: nice... now the file exported appear like this: **Inventário Livros (20-05-2015).xls-**. With a dash in the end of the file extension, don't know what's happening. thanks... @PeterPaulKiefer

Comment: There is a space after .xls. That might be the problem. I don't know.

Comment: I don´t belive... this is embarrassing kkkkkkkk. You right mate. The problem was the spaces. Problem solved =D

Comment: That' what I learned from thirty years of software development: in most cases the small details cause the problems. In german we say "Glück muss der Mensch haben", that means: a person should be blessed with luck. This time I saw the space. I'm glad to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added a http header "Content-Disposition" to yout response. This header tells the Chrome Browser, and others too ;-), which filename the browser should show in its file save windows. Simply add .xls to your filename and the browser will use it.

Comment: Here is a list of http header fields: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_HTTP-Headerfelder

Comment: I have done that @PeterPaulKiefer... now the file comes with the *.xls extension plus an **-** in the end of the file. kkkkkk ???